# different ways of removing row from javascript table

Tags: javascript

I want to remove particular rows from table using 3 different function. Functions deleteRow() and deleteRow2 seem to work well, but deleteRow3 not. Can you explain me why?

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable">
     <tr>
       <td>Row 1</td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Row 2</td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow2(this)"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Row 3</td>
       <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow3(this)"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>

  <script>
    function deleteRow(el){   // this function works
      var i = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
    }
    function deleteRow2(el){  // this also
      var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }
    function deleteRow3(el){  // and this dont' work
      var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
      document.getElementById("myTable").removeChild(row);
    }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the browser is inserting a `<tbody>` element into your table, thus making the row no longer a direct child of the table, it is now a child of the `<tbody>`.

This would work:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").children[0].removeChild(row);
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser inserts a `<tbody>` tag between your `<table>` and `<tr>` - so `row` is not a direct child of `#myTable`.